# Вычислить и вывести на экран в виде таблицы значение функции, заданной с помощью ряда Тейлора, на интервале от Хнач до Хкон с шагом dX с точностью Е

Tags: while

[image: Формула для вычислений.]
Задание нужно решить через While, do while
Каждая строка таблицы должна содержать значение аргумента, значение функции и количество просуммированных членов ряда. Для вычисления последующего члена ряда использовать рекуррентную формулу:
(не факт,что верный)Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
 float X1, X2, d, E,e, slog, i, summ;
 printf("Введите Хначальное меньше нуля\n");
 scanf_s("%fl", &X1);
 printf("Введите Хконечное меньше нуля\n");
 scanf_s("%fl", &X2);
 printf("Введите шаг\n");
 scanf_s("%fl", &d);
 printf("***** Таблица значений *****\n");
 E = 0.0001;
 e = 2,71828;
 for (i = X1; i >= X2; i += d)
 {
  int stepen = 1;
  int faktorial = 1;
  slog = 1;
  summ = 1;
  int koll = 1;
  while (E <= slog);
  {
   slog = (pow((-1), stepen) * pow(i, stepen)) / faktorial;
   summ += slog;
   stepen += 1;
   faktorial = faktorial + (faktorial + 1);
   koll++;
   printf("Для Х=%fl Сумма будет равна %fl Koличество слагаемых %d\n", &i, &summ, &koll);
   float otvet = pow(e, -i);
   printf("е в степени -%fl = %fl", &i, otvet);
  }
}
 printf("*****Конец таблицы*****");

return 0;
}
```